# Adding images & texts one below another based on previous image /text position

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jspdf

How to add images or texts sequentially by calculating the y cordinates in jspdf

[Here is the demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jspdf-app-bbrekz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I could not find any method that can help me calculate the Y cordinate of last image so that I can add next image or text after it

```
    doc.text('Something written over here', 15, 18);
    doc.addImage(base64_img, 10, 20, 0, 0); // should be added with y position based on text that ends above it.
    doc.addImage(base64_img, 10, 40, 0, 0); // < 40 should be some val that should be next value of Y after 1st image
    doc.addImage(base64_img, 10, 70, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to 'play' with the size of the chars and the lenght of your string, something like this:

```
    const yourText = 'Something written over here';
    const sizeChar = 20;

    const textWith = yourText.length * sizeChar;
    
    doc.setFontSize(sizeChar);
    doc.text(yourText, 15, 18);


    doc.addImage(base64_img, 10, textWith, 0, 0);
```